# Python list to make double qoute around string and pass to api

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, rest

Python list to make double quotes around string and pass to API, which requires this to pass as list of double quote string,

API data to pass:

```
data = {
    "styles" : styleList
}
```

it is working when I put manually:

```
["A123", "B123", "C131", "D231"]
```

But not with:

```
['A123', 'B123', 'C131', 'D231']
```

Things tried and not helpful:

1. Append double quotes around string.

```
styleList = ["\"" + style + "\"" for style in styleList]
```

2. Replace single quotes with double quotes.

```
styleList = [style.replace("'","") for style in styleList]
```

3. Dump as JSON.

```
styleList = json.dumps(styleList)
```

All are only helpful to print not to pass with API.

Comment: How are you passing data to the api? `json.dumps({'styles': styleList})` should give you exactly what you want... or, if you're using requests and making a post request, you should be to do: `requests.post('some_url', json={'styles': styleList})`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a string representation of your list.

With `styleList = ["\"" + style + "\"" for style in styleList]` you create " around the items of your list: `['a','b'] --> ['"a"','"b"']`

Use

```
data = { "styles" : repr(styleList) }`
```

`repr` will create a string representation of your list: [repr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr)

```
data = [1,2,3,'tata',8.9]

r = repr(data)                      # "[1, 2, 3, 'tata', 8.9]"
```

If you need numbers quoted as well, use

```
# convert anything to its string representation
r = repr( [str(e) for e in data] )  # "['1', '2', '3', 'tata', '8.9']"
```

Comment: I suspect this is an XY question and actually the OP doesn't need this at all... in fact - I'm guessing they're looking to pass json data to an api and forcing stuff like this is either unnecessary or will break things...but guess we'll see...

Comment: Thanks @JonClements, There is issue with API request itself, and it works fine with single quotes also.  
Thanks PatrickArtner, This is right way to convert single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: @rocky but if you're sending JSON data then json.dumps will ensure strings are correctly quoted *and* escaped for you... (Nested " for instance). You shouldn't have/want to be doing any of this. You should just build a python dict you want to send (your data) and then json.dumps all of it - not the individual bits.

Comment: @rocky I second Jon Clements here - especially manually quoting/escaping is dificult to do so, please try Jon Clements suggestions under your question first before handling it yourself. They are safer down the road.